# Jfreechart - Display all x values in a category dataset

Tags: jfreechart

I have drawn a jfreechart using DefaultCategoryDataset. The problem is even I have added around 150 values (as columns and rows) it only shows only the last 11 x values in the graph. Is there a way to make the graph to show all the x values in the range?

Thanks a lot.

My `createDataset()` method is as below.

```
public CategoryDataset createDataset() {
    final String series1 = "Type1";
    final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    String pattern = "\\s";
    Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    String[] myResult = splitter.split(resultText);
    for (String str : myResult) {
        String head = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('('));
        for(int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
            dataset.addValue(parse(str), series1, head);
        }
    }
    return dataset;
}
```

And I have created the JFreechart as LineChart.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code it's hard to spot the problem. You might compare your `createDataset()` method to this [`BarChartDemo`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.64). A new category and values may be added, as shown.

```
String category6 = "Category 6";
...
dataset.addValue(1.0, series1, category6);
dataset.addValue(2.0, series2, category6);
dataset.addValue(3.0, series3, category6);
```

Addendum:

> I need to add a scrollbar to the x axis as well.

I've never had to do this but I see there is a horizontal [scrolling example](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) named `SlidingCategoryDatasetDemo2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply trashgod. I have edited my question to show the code. I need to add a scrollbar to the x axis as well.

Comment: You might step through the string parsing code to see how many values it finds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The parsing code works fine and it parses all the values. But the problem is when displaying the graph it shows only the last few values.

Comment: Sorry, I can't view the example you have provided in the link. They charge money to give the developer guide. So I am not in a position to buy it. :(

Comment: Another approach to using `SlidingCategoryDataset` is suggested here:  http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=29436